# Direct parent change callback using ancestry gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I am trying to check if the direct parent of any record changed to do some stuff. I have searched a lot but I didn't find `node.parent_changed?`. I only found `node.ancestry_changed?`. But the problem with that is, it returns any node that has any changes in the path of ancestors.

My question is, how can I check only on direct parent changes in my `before_save` callback?